# AngularJS Calling ng-blur only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two input box and need to concatenate value from first input box to other once value to second input box is entered.

Problem I faced doing this with ng-blur is it executes function multiple time for multiple blurs. I added count for ng-blur with condition for only first blur and It worked.

I feel somehow Its not efficient way. Is there any other way to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.1"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<input placeholder="sample" ng-model="input1"> 
 <input ng-blur="counting(input2)" placeholder="sample" ng-model="input2"> 
count : {{count}}
</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.name = 'World';
 $scope.count =0;
 $scope.counting = function(value){

 if($scope.count===0)
 {
    if($scope.input1 && $scope.input2){
       var val1=$scope.input1;
       var val2=$scope.input2;
       $scope.input2=val1+val2;
     }
   }
   $scope.count++;

  }
 });
```

See [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/E7UuiU9wwmRydBrlL1O1?p=preview)

Comment: what you wanted to achieve here?

Comment: same result in other way if possible avoiding if conditions

Comment: I mean to ask, ng-blur is behaving correctly..why you wanted to fire it only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is most likely the behavior that's desired (please be more specific), it's better to append the contents of the first input when the second input is exited and **remove** the appended contents when the second input is entered again.

IMPORTANT - The general rule of thumb is if you use an ng-model in an input element, make sure the variable you're referencing has a dot in it. This strange sounding rule is due to a nasty but common issue involving automatically generated child scopes in angular 1. I've modified the code to account for that as well:

...

```
<input placeholder="sample" ng-model="inputs.input1">
<input ng-blur="appendText()"
       ng-focus="restoreOriginalText()"
       placeholder="sample"
       ng-model="inputs.input2">
```

...

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.inputs = {
    input1: '',
    input2: ''
  };
  $scope.name = 'World'; // not used
  $scope.originalText = $scope.inputs.input2;

  $scope.appendText = function () {
    $scope.originalText = $scope.inputs.input2;
    $scope.inputs.input2 = $scope.inputs.input1 + $scope.inputs.input2;
  }

  $scope.restoreOriginalText = function () {
    $scope.inputs.input2 = $scope.originalText;
  }

});
```

Comment: well...logic looks good but i used in my application, its deleting whole value from input2 and shifting its focus to next tab

Comment: when is it doing that? when you enter input2?

Comment: @ronypatil: you're likely suffering from a nasty but common issue involving automatically generated child scopes. it's beyond the scope of this question (pun intended) to explain it, but the general rule of thumb is if you use an `ng-model` in an `input` element, make sure the variable you're referencing has a dot in it.  add an "inputs" object to your controller's scope and move input1 and input2 into it. then change the ng-model attributes to `inputs.input1` and `inputs.input2`.

Comment: @ronypatil: I've modified the code to account for the issue I mentioned above.

Comment: hey thanks !! it works...the only issue is if you focus again in input2 , the value of input1 disappears for that time.Does this affect anything in future? See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ElHBoaLWB2A3UpnfUUcE?p=preview)

Comment: @ronypatil: No, because when you leave input2 again the value of input1 is added back. As for your case, only you know if this behavior fits your needs because you still haven't explained exactly what you need this code to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Lu0Kjoxovv8UpbcWS1a?p=preview)

```
<input ng-change="counting(input2)"placeholder="sample" ng-model="input2" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }">
```

It will fire after a half second of no typing, causing the now `ng-change` to fire:

```
$scope.counting = function(value){
 $scope.input2= $scope.input1 + $scope.input2;
}
```

**EDIT**
    If concerned about Alvin's comment you could hack it in via:

```
$scope.counting = function(value){
 $scope.input2= $scope.input2.replace($scope.input1,'');
 $scope.input2= $scope.input1 + $scope.input2;
}
```

Comment: looks good. May I know how this debounce work in this context?

Comment: Debounce is useful, but you still have a similar issue. If the user continues to type after the delay the contents of the first input is appended again.

Comment: @AlvinThompson addressed.

Comment: @ronypatil Basically the debounce option puts a delay on angular firing off an internal watch on the ng-model. By making it ng-change, it will only know it changed after there is enough delay (user stops typing) and fire once.

Comment: @KreepN: that won't work because the value of input1 may have changed in the mean time.

Comment: @AlvinThompson I'm aware of that, but I'm sure you can make up infinite scenarios in which a solution will not work. You even state in your answer that the behavior needs to be more specific...

Comment: ...or you could easily alter your code to store the original value, instead of using this ridiculous, slower, and buggy 'replace' method.

Comment: If you're happy with the quality of your code, so be it. I will point out that maybe if the OP asked for code that doesn't append the value of input1 more than once, maybe he wants code that doesn't append the value of input1 more than once.

Comment: @AlvinThompson And I get that, half the time people want the solution that does it all, and the other half they want the most basic solution. If he knows input1 will never change more than once, then it works, if not, it can be improved. We're not here to read minds and do other people's work, but get them on the right path.

Comment: In bigger scenario, I am using typeheader for my input box and having fetched options from Json. The Problem with this solution is function executes as soon as i start to enter any word. This should execute when  option from typeheader for input2 has been selected

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS has very simple way of handling forms.

Do something like this -

**View**

```
<form name="myForm">
       <input name="input1"
              placeholder="sample"
              ng-model="input1"> 
       <input name="input2"
              ng-blur="updateValue()"
              placeholder="sample"
              ng-model="input2"> 
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.updateValue = function(){
    alert($scope.myForm.input2.$dirty);
    // If input2 is dirty that means user has
    // interected with that field concatenate value
    if($scope.myForm.input2.$dirty){
        $scope.input2 = $scope.input1 +""+ $scope.input2;
        // Set input2 to pristine so now on blur 
        // it will not execute it again
        $scope.myForm.input2.$setPristine();
     }
  }
});
```

See this updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OGCY1jMLYfHNyiysREVR?p=preview%22plunker%22) hope it will help you.

**P.S.** -  After changing input2 once blur function will be called but it will not concatenate again, but if user now changes input2 again then concatenate will happen once again that issue you have to handle seprately.
My suggestion is that disable input2 after changing its value once.

Comment: This only partially fixes the issue; input1 will still be appended to input2 multiple times if you change input2, exit input2, change input2 again, and exit input2 again. You need to store the original value of input2 somewhere.

Comment: Also, this code suffers from the child scope issue I mentioned in my answer. See there for how to fix it.

Comment: @AlvinThompson thanks for your suggestion my point is ,ss i said after changing  input2 once it can be disabled so user cant change it. It will be enabled again if user changes input1 again.